# Can't detect Textfield unfocus lister

Tags: flutter

How can I detect when a textField loses focus? I tried googling it, but only found ways to detect when a textfield gets focused.

```
TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      minLines: 2,
      maxLines: null,
      controller: fieldController,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `FocusNode` and `addListener` method, like this:

```
//define _node and _focused virables in header class
FocusNode _node = FocusNode(); 
bool _focused = false;

//handleFocusChange in initState method
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _node.addListener(_handleFocusChange);
  }

 void _handleFocusChange() {
    if (_node.hasFocus != _focused) {
      setState(() {
        _focused = _node.hasFocus;
      });
    }
  }

//use _node in TextField
TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      minLines: 2,
      maxLines: null,
      focusNode:_node,
      controller: fieldController,
    ),
```

Comment: Does this have to be done in a statefull widget, or can it be done in a StatelessWidget?

Comment: It's up to you. If you don't want to rebuild the page, use StatelessWidget, Otherwise, the opposite

Comment: If you use StatelessWidget you should listen to the FocusChange in the constructor, Of course, you won't be able to use setState() method, in this case